# How to pass data to ViewModel from AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel, autocompletetextview

I need to pass an id of clicked object from AutoCompleteTextView to ViewModel. Here I have a binding adapter to set a spinner with objects for AutoCompleteTextView.

```
@BindingAdapter("bindAutocomplete")
fun bindAutocomplete(textView: AutoCompleteTextView, cities: List<City>?){
 cities?.let {
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<City>(
    textView.context,
    R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
    it)

    textView.setAdapter(adapter)
 }
}
```

My question is: where should I place my OnItemClickListener, in this adapter above or in the Fragment class like in code below?

The problem for first way is that I dont know how to access my ViewModel from Binding Adapter. And for the second, if I put this listener in the Fragment class isn`t it breaks a pattern, because initializations of the Biniding Adapter and of the OnItemClickListener are not synchronized?

So I need to pass a city.id to some method in my ViewModel.

```
binding.autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val city = parent.adapter.getItem(position) as City
        binding.viewModel.getWeatherProperties(city.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved this task just by using an Observer, I am not sure if it is even possible to use a Two-way binding with AutoCompleteTextView here. Probably its because of SetOnItemClickListener has no built-in support for two-way data binding.

```
 viewModel.autocompleteArray.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                it?.let {
                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<City>(
                        binding.autoCompleteTextView.context,
                        R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        it)

                    binding.autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter)

                    binding.autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, 
                    position, id ->

                        val s = parent.adapter.getItem(position) as City
                        viewModel.getWeatherProperties(s.id)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two way data binding like below to pass data to viewmodel..

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView  
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"  
    android:layout_width="200dp"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="92dp"  
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"  
    android:text="@={viewmodel.rememberMe}"  
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"  
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: How can I pull out the id from clicked object? Should I use an Inverse Binding Adapter then?

Comment: @jericho You search the `text` in your `List` to find its id.